# Spritekit: Applying Angular Impulse to all surrounding node of exploding node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I am making a simple game in spritekit where the screen is full of balls with physics bodies. when the player taps a ball the ball explodes. I want to apply an angular impulse at the point of touch which will push all the surrounding balls away like a real world explosion. I tried fields but they are not really good as all the physics field nodes are forces not impulses. I checked all the impulse methods but they are only to apply force to the node itself. I also tried this:

```
self.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(100)
```

and

```
self.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulse: CGVector, at: CGPoint)
```

thinking it would apply impulse to all child nodes in the scene (all the balls are child of the scene) but had no effect.

I thought this would be very simple but I am out of ideas.

appreciate your time. cheers

Comment: Are you sure about angular impulse? The explosion sounds like a normal impulse (vector impulse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is not a real-world explosion simulation but can help you as an idea.

[image]

I'm making actions like this on each touched node:

```
node.run(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.0),
    SKAction.scale(to: 10, duration: 0.1),
    SKAction.removeFromParent()
]))
```

You can get this example here: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/BoxWithBalls/BoxWithBalls/GameScene.swift

Comment: This is a smart approach and it worked for me. Thank you very much